# In a triangle is there an angle splitter formula like angle bisector theorem but generalized?

Tags: triangles

A segment starting from a vertex of a triangle splits that angle in 2 arbitrary parts.
It also splits the opposite triangle side in 2 parts.
Can a relationship be established between the angle parts and the side parts, like the proportional relationship in the case of bisector?
Here's a picture:
[image]
For simplicity I drew the triangle as right, with one leg being twice as long as the other. The blue segment is bisector, magenta is a median and red splits the right angle in two of 30 and 60 degrees respectively.
I tried to reason something from the picture but I couldn't.

Comment: Perhaps **Stewart's theorem** is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we have a figure as the one below. [Stewart's Theorem](https://brilliant.org/wiki/stewarts-theorem/) states the following relationship between the sides of a triangle and a cevian:

$$ d^2=\frac{c^2n+b^2m}{m+n}-m\cdot n$$

$\hspace{3cm}$ [image: Stewart]

For a relationship between sides and angles, you should use the law of sines and the law of cosines. Alternatively, you can try to form special triangles ($30°-60°-90°$, $45°-45°-90°$, $15°-75°-90°$, etc.) to solve specific problems.